# Tikz: Drawing lines with \draw[opacity = 0] produces .dvi files in which the lines are visible

Tags: tikz-pgf, dvi, dvipdf

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       % Bounding box coordinates
       \coordinate (q) at (1,  0);
       \coordinate (t) at (1,  8);
       \coordinate (r) at (12, 8);
       \coordinate (s) at (12, 0);

       % Draw the (invisible) bounding box
       \draw[opacity = 0] (q) -- (t) -- (r) -- (s) -- (q);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The above MWE compiles using `pdflatex` to produce an empty page, but if I compile to .dvi using `latex`, then the resultant dvi file has the rectangle displayed! How can i fix this?

(I need an invisible bounding box in order to draw a 4-part figure, in some of which the box is visible, hence I don't really have an option to remove the box completely. Also, for reason not technical, I need the .dvi file to be rendered correctly as well!)

Comment: If I'm not wrong `dvi` does not work well with `tikz`. Why do you need a `dvi` file?

Comment: Why not use `\path (q) -- (t) -- (r) -- (s) -- (q);` or `\draw[white] (q) -- (t) -- (r) -- (s) -- (q);`?

Comment: Or you can use to clip `\clip (q) -- (t) -- (r) -- (s) -- (q);`

Comment: @Sigur: The MAJOR issue is, all PDF's show this supposedly invisible box **when I
print using Google Chrome**, but the PDF does not show the figure when viewed
on-screen! Since the box shows up on .dvi, I'm figuring that its a latex issue
rather than a Chrome issue!

Comment: @Sigur: Your idea of using `\draw[white]` seems to be the easiest solution to my problem, but doesn't really answer the question why the lines are visible (in dvi or when printed with Google Chrome). Nevertheless, if u post it as an answer, I'm bound to accept it :)

Comment: Also try `\draw[draw=none]`, that should give the same result.

Comment: @TCSGrad, I guess that the opacity is a feature of the PDF viewer. So if you print, the line will be there. DVI viewer does not have this feature to lead with opacity objects.

Comment: So the question is: do you want the box visible on printed version? Or you want the box only to clip the image?

Comment: @Sigur: No, I don't want it visible in some of my images, for which I'll now try the 2 options listed above (`white` doesn't seem too generic after all, as I've seen ppl taking prints in colored paper!), so I'll try `clip` and `none` to see which works best (or if they are equivalent!)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, DVI and TikZ do not always play nicely together. Here, the problem is `opacity`, because transparency is not supported by DVI. Several workarounds were posted in the comments.

However, your question as posed is an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The proper way to specify an explicit bounding box without drawing it is to use the `\useasboundingbox` command or, equivalently, `\path[use as bounding box]`.

Any one of the commented lines in the code (most of the path you specified is really unnecessary) will give the same bounding box as the last one I've left uncommented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
x% just to illustrate width
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Bounding box coordinates
  \coordinate (q) at (1,  0);
  \coordinate (t) at (1,  8);
  \coordinate (r) at (12, 8);
  \coordinate (s) at (12, 0);

  % Draw the (invisible) bounding box
%  \useasboundingbox (q) -- (t) -- (r) -- (s) -- (q);
%  \useasboundingbox (q) -- (t) -- (r) -- (s) -- cycle;
%  \useasboundingbox (q) -- (t) -- (r) -- (s);
%  \useasboundingbox (q) -- (t) -- (r) -- cycle;
%  \useasboundingbox (q) rectangle (r);
%  \useasboundingbox (q) -- (r);
  \path[use as bounding box] (q) -- (r);
\end{tikzpicture}%
x% just to illustrate width
\end{document}
```